# DRUPAL: ordering the content in the back-end without using Views

Tags: drupal

I would like to order alphabetically the content in my Drupal back-end

Is there any simpler method than using Views module or hacking the code for doing it ?

I don't need an ordering selector, just to statically order the nodes differently.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this is *very simple* with Views.

1. Install Views module.
2. Go to `/admin/build/views/list`.
3. Click "enable" next to whatever default node list you want to override (probably "admin_content").
4. Find the "Sort criteria" section of the edit page:

   - Remove "Node: updated date".
   - Click the add button, choose "Node: title", "ascending".
5. Save, and you're done!

Answer (score 1):

1. View is the simplest/easiest solution.
2. An alternative *solution* would be to use a jQuery plugin and do sorting via js, but that would only work for the items on the page and not globally.
3. You could also create your own display using `hook_menu` in a custom module.
4. Yet another solution would be to rewrite the SQL of `node_admin_nodes` function to implement a sorting that way, or use `hook_form_alter` and create your own implementation of `node_admin_nodes`. But that would be the most time consuming and complex route to take that I don't want to describe how you would do it in details and I would definitely adwise strongly against it. But it's a possibility if you really don't want to use views…

Answer (score 1):

The core content view 'Edit' is annoyingly unconfigurable. You will need Views.